# How to display server response for HTTP errors in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I'm working on a React Native app. We recently made a change to an API call, where it can respond with 500 and an error message detailing the problem so it can be presented to the user. The API response looks like:

```
{
    "error": ["Renter contact info for User 1 missing"]
}
```

On the client, we're using the standard `fetch()` method to asynchronously make our request, and resolving the Promise in order to pull the response object out. When I log the response after a call that should trigger a 500, the object looks like:

```
{type: "default", status: 500, ok: false, statusText: undefined, headers: Headers…}
```

Here's our internal `request()` method we use for all API calls:

```
export function request(endpoint:string, parameters:Object, method:string = HTTP.get, timeout:number = 3000):Promise{

  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const payload = {
      method,
      headers: {
        'Accept': CONTENT_TYPE,
        'Content-Type': CONTENT_TYPE,
        'Authorization': `Basic ${base64.encode(Config.API_TOKEN)}`,
        'Auth-Token': await Agents.authToken,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(parameters),
    }

    fetch(apiUrl(endpoint), payload)
      .then(response => {
        if(!response.ok) {
          // ******************
          // this is where the 500 error state is caught, but my response object doesn't contain the message sent from the server.
          reject(response)
          // ******************
        }

        return response
      })
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject)
  })
}
```

How can I ensure the response object contains the error message from the server so I can properly display it to my user?

Comment: React Native isn’t affected by lack of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response, right? If it is, I think that would be the reason you can’t access any properties of the response. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43361959/441757

Answer (score 1):

```
fetch(apiUrl(endpoint), payload)
      .then(response => {
        if(!response.ok) {
          response.json().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);// your error response
          },function(error) {
            //json error
          });
          reject(response)
          // ******************
        }

        return response
      })
```

response is a ReadableStream object. You need to use .json() to parse